# Azure HDInsight Metrics

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I have an HDInsight cluster running that is connected to a Log Analytics Workspace/AppInsights. But the metrics I get there are just global ones like "number of apps running". I would like to get metrics at application level, e.g. status of a streaming app. Useful information seems to be scattered over different locations e.g. YarnUI, but not available in Azure for alerting purposes. Does anyone have an idea how to customize HDInsight here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, Azure HDInsight does not support customers to customize which logs/metrics to send to Log Analytics. When customers enable the integration with Azure Monitoring, HDInsight has a set of predefined tables which will be sent to log analytics.

We are actively working on enabling customers to select metrics to log analytics. I will keep updated this answer once it available.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Custom tables in LA?

[image]
Please have a look here-[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-oms-log-analytics-tutorial#install-hdinsight-cluster-management-solutions](http://Link) . It monitors Kafka, storm along with Spark. Maybe you can also check the code which I have written to monitor on an application-level-https://dzone.com/articles/customized-alerts-for-hadoop-jobs-using-yarn-rest